# Casting issue in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I observed a piece of code which is not giving compile time or run time error but should give:

```
message: string // this variable is of type string -- L1 <br>
abc: somedatatype //lets say abc is of some data type -- L2

message = <any> abc; // this should give error but does not -- L3
```

I strongly believe this should give compile time error but it does not. Please clarify or suggest how we can get it corrected as it seems to be a serious issue.

Comment: thanks for the edit @jonrsharpe

Comment: If you want the compiler to complain about the assignment, *don't* explicitly hint `abc` to `any`.

Comment: so do you mean that it says that variable on the right will take the data type of the variable on the left by using <any> ? Then how will you explain string = <any> object giving me a garbage value. It is better if user gets to know this during compile time itself

Comment: It's not a *cast*, it's an *assertion*. Why are you doing it to begin with? It would be better if the user didn't do things that make no sense, but unfortunately that's very difficult to implement at a language level!

Comment: i said i came across this piece of code and since i have worked with other languages, i know this is not a good practice.

Comment: Then you'll need to talk to whoever wrote it to find out why they did it.

Answer (score 3):

Why should it throw a compile error when you explicitly cast it to `any`? You are telling the compiler to trust you and do not type check. See [Type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

> Sometimes you’ll end up in a situation where you’ll know more about a value than TypeScript does. Usually this will happen when you know the type of some entity could be more specific than its current type.
>
> Type assertions are a way to tell the compiler “trust me, I know what I’m doing.” A type assertion is like a type cast in other languages, but performs no special checking or restructuring of data. It has no runtime impact, and is used purely by the compiler. TypeScript assumes that you, the programmer, have performed any special checks that you need.

Comment: see if i say string =<string> any; -- this is correct
but if i say string = <any> object -- how does this seem logical?

Comment: @hstg because if it's `any` it's considered to have *all* properties, including those of a `string`. How else *would* it be interpreted? You might find it useful to understand the difference between structural and nominal typing (see e.g. https://medium.com/@thejameskyle/type-systems-structural-vs-nominal-typing-explained-56511dd969f4) as this may illustrate why other languages behave differently.